# To save data generated in a R shiny app in a .csv file in Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, shiny

I have a working R shiny app which is being hosted from our internal org Amazon AWS server. Now, Users will generate data on that Shiny app using different widgets provided there. Now, I need to save all the data generated in one session into a file that is stored in our internal Amazon S3 bucket.

The possible challenge that we are facing is how to save these data when multiple users could generate data using that Shiny App and then need to be saved and reloaded back to the Shiny app further if needed.

We just can't lose any data even if two users simultaneously add data using the Shiny App.

Please guide what could be our best approach.

I did follow the guideline provided here :
https://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/

But, is there a way where we don't need to create as many .csv files as we have a number of users accessing the app.

Comment: [This post](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html) may give a few hints on how to approach this.

Comment: Thanks , but the same post has been taken from the same link only which I posted.Just wanted to know that if that's the only way available till date.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't need to create as many .csv files as we have a number of users accessing the app"? Do you mean you want to be able to share csv files between different users? Or not save a file if someone else has already created the same data?